# Validate correctness of a regular expression - Ruby/Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I got a regular expression like this:

```
/\b[A-Z0-9._%a-zöäüÖÄÜ\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-zöüäÖÜÄ\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/
```

How can I check via Ruby/RoR if this string is a valid regular expression?

Comment: Well I want to check in my code if a submitted regular expression(by the user) is correct.

Comment: To which field in your `db` that submitted regular expression save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't raise errors, it's a valid regex. :)

```
def valid_regex?(str)
  Regexp.new(str)
  true
rescue
  false
end

valid_regex?('[a-b]') # => true
valid_regex?('[[a-b]') # => false
```